# MongoDB entries sinde my .bash_profile are not recognized (Mac OS)

Tags: mongodb, macos, mongoose, terminal, iterm

I installed MongoDB on my Macbook (Catalina 10.15.3) and placed all the necessary entries in my **.bash_profile.** However, these entries are not recognized, so I have to manually enter the following again and again in order to start MongoDB (for each new terminal):

```
export MONGO_PATH=/Users/codehan/Desktop/MongoDB/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.3
export PATH=$MONGO_PATH/bin:$PATH
```

Otherwise I always get the following in the terminal:

```
zsh: command not found: mongo
```

But as soon as I enter `export MONGO_PATH=/Users/codehan/Desktop/MongoDB/mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.2.3` and `export PATH=$MONGO_PATH/bin:$PATH` in my terminal it works again.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: zsh does not use .bash_profile. Try put in $HOME/.zshrc

Comment: @Philippe Works like a charm, thank you! Post your comment as an answer please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With zsh, the configuration file is $HOME/.zshrc